# How can I temporary save data? such as shopping cart in android app

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, global-variables

I am the begginer android developer. I have a problem about saving shopping cart data temporary. It's a custom shirts app. Guest should select collar, cuffs, and so on.
I used listview to show these selected items and options which guest selected.

```
public class Cart_item_list {
private static int cart_itemimage;
private static String cart_itemname;
private static String cart_itemprice;
private static String cart_collar;
private static String cart_cuffs;
private static String cart_placket;
private static String cart_pocket;
private static String cart_fit;
private static String cart_initial;

public static int getCart_itemimage() {
    return cart_itemimage;
}

public static void setCart_itemimage(int cart_itemimage) {
    Cart_item_list.cart_itemimage = cart_itemimage;
}

public static String getCart_itemname() {
    return cart_itemname;
}

public static void setCart_itemname(String cart_itemname) {
    Cart_item_list.cart_itemname = cart_itemname;
}

public static String getCart_itemprice() {
    return cart_itemprice;
}

public static void setCart_itemprice(String cart_itemprice) {
    Cart_item_list.cart_itemprice = cart_itemprice;
}

public static String getCart_collar() {
    return cart_collar;
}

public static void setCart_collar(String cart_collar) {
    Cart_item_list.cart_collar = cart_collar;
}

public static String getCart_cuffs() {
    return cart_cuffs;
}

public static void setCart_cuffs(String cart_cuffs) {
    Cart_item_list.cart_cuffs = cart_cuffs;
}

public static String getCart_placket() {
    return cart_placket;
}

public static void setCart_placket(String cart_placket) {
    Cart_item_list.cart_placket = cart_placket;
}

public static String getCart_pocket() {
    return cart_pocket;
}

public static void setCart_pocket(String cart_pocket) {
    Cart_item_list.cart_pocket = cart_pocket;
}

public static String getCart_fit() {
    return cart_fit;
}

public static void setCart_fit(String cart_fit) {
    Cart_item_list.cart_fit = cart_fit;
}

public static String getCart_initial() {
    return cart_initial;
}

public static void setCart_initial(String cart_initial) {
    Cart_item_list.cart_initial = cart_initial;
}


public Cart_item_list(int cart_itemimage, String cart_itemname, String cart_itemprice, String cart_collar, String cart_cuffs, String cart_placket, String cart_pocket, String cart_fit, String cart_initial) {
    this.cart_itemimage = cart_itemimage;
    this.cart_itemname = cart_itemname;
    this.cart_itemprice = cart_itemprice;
    this.cart_collar = cart_collar;
    this.cart_cuffs = cart_cuffs;
    this.cart_placket = cart_placket;
    this.cart_pocket = cart_pocket;
    this.cart_fit = cart_fit;
    this.cart_initial = cart_initial;

}
```

}

it's the item list for listview adapter.

```
package com.example.yeong.shifendingzhi;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Cart_item_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<Cart_item_list> cart_item_listArrayList;


public Cart_item_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Cart_item_list> cart_item_listArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.cart_item_listArrayList = cart_item_listArrayList;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cart_item_listArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return cart_item_listArrayList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cart_listview, null);
    ImageView selected_item_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.selected_item_image);
    TextView selected_cart_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.selected_cart_name);
    TextView selected_cart_cuffs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.selected_cart_cuffs);
    TextView selected_cart_initial = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.selected_cart_initial);
    TextView selected_cart_placket = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.selected_cart_placket);
    TextView selected_cart_fit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.selected_cart_fit);
    TextView selected_cart_pocket = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.selected_cart_pocket);
    TextView selected_cart_price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.selected_cart_price);
    TextView selected_cart_collar = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.selected_cart_collar);

    selected_cart_name.setText(cart_item_listArrayList.get(i).getCart_itemname());
    selected_cart_cuffs.setText(cart_item_listArrayList.get(i).getCart_cuffs());
    selected_cart_initial.setText(cart_item_listArrayList.get(i).getCart_initial());
    selected_cart_placket.setText(cart_item_listArrayList.get(i).getCart_placket());
    selected_cart_fit.setText(cart_item_listArrayList.get(i).getCart_fit());
    selected_cart_pocket.setText(cart_item_listArrayList.get(i).getCart_pocket());
    selected_cart_price.setText(cart_item_listArrayList.get(i).getCart_itemprice());
    selected_cart_collar.setText(cart_item_listArrayList.get(i).getCart_collar());
    selected_item_image.setImageResource(cart_item_listArrayList.get(i).getCart_itemimage());
    return view;
}
```

}

it's the listview adapter
I tried to create global variable arraylist, and shearched a lot, but all failed, singleton, using appllication.
Could you help me to make global arraylist for listview?
It helps me to save data temporary and chage the arraylist data on another activity.
Thanks.

Comment: use shared preference

Comment: @AvinashMishra well i do not want to use shared preference, i just want to know how to solve this problem just by using global variables.

Comment: Shared preference is what i have used too

Comment: you can use application class also

Comment: @VivekMishra would you please tell me how to use application class to store customer's custom shirts

Comment: @Yeong You can declare the arraylist as static.But I think it's better to use local variables and pass the objects from class to class or store it in sharedpreferences and access it from anywhere as others mentioned.

Comment: you can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430637/android-arraylist-in-application-class

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the Paper library from https://github.com/pilgr/Paper

it is easy to configure and no need to setup any sql kind of connections , its like writing in a text file locally.
I used it and it is solid.
I mainly used it for storing the username and password for Remember Me in the login activity page:

```
 if(ckbRemember.isChecked())
                {
                    Paper.book().write(Common.USER_KEY,edtUsername.getText().toString());
                    Paper.book().write(Common.PWD_KEY,edtPassword.getText().toString());
                }
```

and when you want to clear the data at any time and from any activity is like:

```
Paper.book().destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple POJO class. Make a java class that stores shirts attributes. Then declare a global arraylist with that class as its primitive type.

```
public class Shirt{
    String cuffs;
    String plackets;
    String collars;
    ...

public String getCuff(){...}
public String getCollar(){...}

public void setCuff(){...}
public void setCollar(){...}
}

ArrayList<Shirt> shirts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now you have to either store it in a SharedPreference or some database if you want it to persist. If you don't want storage but need a global context type variable, you can use `Application` class or a static variable maybe depending on whatever your use case is.

**Edit:** A simple [example](http://androidexample.com/Global_Variable_Or_Application_Context_Variable_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=114&aaid=136) of Application class. Do remember to name the package in your Manifest.

Comment: I used intent to collect the shirt's attributes, I want to store customized shirts data for shopping cart, not just one shirt

Comment: I think you will have to use SharedPreferences or some database, if you want your database to persist. @DDerTyp has already given you the code. Go ahead, use it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store all of those values longer (e.g. for a few days or if the user closes your app) you can store those values in the `shared preferences`:

```
SharedPreferences spInstance = getSharedPreferences("my_identifier", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = spInstance.edit();
spEditor.putString("key", "value");
spEditor.apply(); // Save the data
//Retrieve the data:
SharedPreferences spInstance = getSharedPreferences("my_identifier", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = spInstance.edit();
String myString = spInstance.getString("key", "default-value");
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Android provides several optionsto save persistent application data. The solution you choose depends on your specific needs, such as whether the data should be private, persistent and how much space your data requires. Take a look at [Developers Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)